# Invalid data after declaration in python file including kv code

Tags: python

![kv error][1]

Here is my main code including kv code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

import time 
import random

class FirstScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SecondScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:
<FirstScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        source: 'graphics/color.png'
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False

<SecondScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        source: 'graphics/color1.png'
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
''')

class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
    return root_widget

ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

I have put image in the graphics folder where the main.py file exists and when I run my code, I get invalid data after declaration source property of image. I have checked out so many times, but i don't understand what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Can you give the exact error you get?

Comment: Error : "Invalid data after declaration" i get this error on line " source: 'graphics/color.png' "

Comment: Please fix your indentation inside definistion of `class ScreenManagerApp(App):`. Apart from that I don't see anything wrong with the code as such. I tested it locally and it runs fine with some test images of my own. Can you share the image files that you are using? Also can you share the folder structure of your main.py and graphics folders?

Comment: hey thanks for help it works now...it was an indentation problem...